# Android Custom View onDraw called constantly

Tags: android

I have a custom view and listview in my activity.. Custom view onDraw() method called again and again whenever listview adapter is notified using notifyDataSetChanged().

When there is no update in listview, custom view onDraw() is not called.

Any idea why onDraw called constantly ?

I'm using invalidate() only in onTouch() to redraw the view.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7814617

Comment: To expand, don't call invalidate() anywhere in the `onDraw()` code path.

Comment: I'm not calling invalidate() inside onDraw(). I'm using invalidate() only in onTouch whenever i need.